# SQL query with left join with where condition

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

please help me to correct this query, I need the data with this that senderId

```
select count(tg."transferGroupId"),
       tg."transferGroupId",
       tg."senderId",
       tg."receiverId",
       tg."createdAt",
       u."firstName" 
from kit.kit_transfers as tg 
where tg."senderId"='30b81071-0167-4736-a162-103a2165be3d' 
left join users as u on tg."receiverId"=u.id 
group by tg."transferGroupId",  tg."senderId",tg."receiverId",tg."createdAt",u."firstName"
```

Comment: MySQL <> Postgresql please correct your tags and take a look on [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: The WHERE clause needs to go _after_ the JOIN clause (which is part to the FROM clause).

Comment: Maybe remove `tg."createdAt"` from the SELECT and GROUP BY lists in order to have COUNT bigger than 1.

Comment: Please update your question to show sample data for the tables and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(tg."transferGroupId"),
       tg."transferGroupId",
       tg."senderId",
       tg."receiverId",
       tg."createdAt",
       u."firstName"
from kit.kit_transfers as tg
left join users as u on tg."receiverId"=u.id
where tg."senderId"='30b81071-0167-4736-a162-103a2165be3d'
group by tg."transferGroupId",  tg."senderId",tg."receiverId",tg."createdAt",u."firstName"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).